# How can I make my calendar in corporate Google account visible to someone outside? (But only availability)

Tags: gmail, google, google-calendar

The company I work for uses Google mail, calendar etc. I need to arrange a number of meetings but instead of emailing to people when I am available I would like to provide a limited access to my Google calendar, which only says whether I am available or not but not any information about existing meetings. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your calendar, on the left:

- Go into the 'My Calendars' drop down option
- Once in here click the down arrow to the right of the calender you wish to share
- Select 'Share this Calendar' and a new screen will pop up
- Select 'Make this calendar public'
- Select 'Show only free/busy (hide details)' from the drop-down list
- Press 'Save'

Your friends/co-workers/colleagues can now see your calendar (to the degree you specify) by adding it in the "Other Calenders" section of their Google Calendars using your account email address as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

That would be "free/busy" sharing. Look under the "share" settings of the calendar you want people to have access to.

You can either make your calendar public and only share the free/busy values, or you can invite individual people to see your calendar and, again, you can limit them to only seeing free/busy.